# external javascript files not loading when published to my server

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My ASP.NET MVC app uses some external javascript and jquery files. Everything works just fine on my dev machine. As soon as I post it to my server none of the .js files even load.
I have used Url.Content() as well as an app helper with the same result. They work fine on the dev machine but don't even load on when published to the server. I am really at a wall and have no idea what this could be. Any ideas what I could try next? Thanks

I have tried

```
<script src="../../Scripts/SiteMaster.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

as well as

```
<script src='<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/SiteMaster.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

both work on the dev machine neither work on the server.

Comment: can you post "how" you're linking to your external js files? `<link>` tag or what?

Comment: Yes of course. Post is updated with these. thanks

Comment: And you've confirmed the files are on the server?

Comment: Are you sure your server has access to that ../../ directory?

Comment: Jfar, I just double confirmed that the files are there... they are there. however now there is a red ! on the script Icon. I don't know what this means.

Comment: They are contained in the inetpub directory. double checked the permissions it should have access.

Comment: Check the Caps.  I know that I have had issues where MyJS.js would work locally, but once I uploaded to my server, I have to use myjs.JS because that is how the file is actually saved.  Just an idea.

Comment: Can you post the `<link>` tag produced on your production server by viewing the page source?

Comment: Here is what is produced by the server and taken from the view source <script src='/Scripts/SiteMaster.js' type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: "Jfar, I just double confirmed that the files are there" - I see below you get a 404 error.  So the files are there but they aren't?

Comment: yup I can go right to the directory on the server. the files are there. when I try to open them in IE i get the 404 error.

Comment: see answer below. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Issue!!! my other programmer created a virtual directory (for some reason) named "scripts" in IIS and had it pointed at a different location on the file system. I appreciate all your help with this! I have fixed it. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 3):

`ResolveUrl` should be all you need

```
<script 
    src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/SiteMaster.js") %>" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

also make sure you've added this IgnoreRoute:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("scripts/{*pathInfo}");
```

Comment: same result. Works on the dev machine not on the server.

Comment: did you try navigating to that url? baseUrl + "/scripts/sitemaster.js"?

Comment: well, there you go, you should check the `/scripts/` folder to see if there are ANY files in there.

Comment: as I said. On the server the files ARE there. But my other programmer created a new virtual directory named scripts and had it pointed to another directory. So when using IE /scripts/ was going to this other directory that the new virtual directory was pointed to. thats where It was getting confusing. thanks for your help though.